# Android make cell not grown in whole screen

Tags: android, kotlin

Im novice in android development. What i want is, to create a simple table populated with cells. In each cell there is 2 text views. First one attached to top(16), left(16), second is: top(16), left(16), bottom(16). So, cell height should be small, however, it grown to entire screen. Where to change it?

There is a screen:

[image]

Text version is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemString"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="itemString"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNumber"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="229dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="itemNumber"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemString" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does your LinearLayout has height = `match_parent`?

Comment: What do you have in the Text version of the layout?

Comment: @ConstOrVar i did change it to wrap_content but in visual editor nothing has changed.

Comment: @Shai i did update question.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban preview don't always work correctly. Does that problem appear on device/emulator?

Comment: @ConstOrVar yes.

Comment: `android:layout_height="229dp"` you could change that manually to something like 50dp and it should appear smaller, but not the best option if you want your app to being displayed correctly on multiple devices

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban `250dp` + `229dp` it's definitely big height. Don't you think so?

Comment: @Shai i dont want to set it manually but i want it to change dynamically

Comment: @ConstOrVar i did not set those values, i only set constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by changing text view attributes to "wrap_content"